# Install GoDaddy SSL to AWS EC2 Instance Linux Server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, amazon-web-services

I have got the ssl certificate(.crt) from the GoDaddy.

What are the steps to follow to install the SSL certificate to AWS EC2 Linux(Apache 2.2.22) Server?

Comment: Godaddy has extensive documentation on this topic http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5346/installing-an-ssl-server-instructions

Answer (score 1):

In order to install a SSL certificate, you should have the following ready,

- SSL Certificate file
- Private key (the one that was generated along the CSR)
- CA Bundle (you can find in GoDaddy's control panel)

If you're running CentOS, make sure you've install mod_ssl module.

```
# yum install mod_ssl
```

Place the following in the Apache configuration file,

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com

    DocumentRoot /path/to/docroot

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/example.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /path/to/example.com.ca

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to create ssl_request_log file.